# Issue with repeater :(

Tags: c++, string

What I am trying to do here is write a function `repeat` that accepts a string and a positive integer n and returns that string repeated n times. Thus `repeat("fho", 3)` would return the string "hohoho".  However, the below test program runs but doesn't display the result or hang. I tried to add a system pause but that didn't help.  What am I missing?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
std::string repeat( const std::string &word, int times ) {
   std::string result ;
   result.reserve(times*word.length()); // avoid repeated reallocation
   for ( int a = 0 ; a < times ; a++ ) 
      result += word ;
   return result ;
}

int main( ) {
   std::cout << repeat( "Ha" , 5 ) << std::endl ;
   return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: What inputs have you tried and how did they not work as you expected?

Comment: this code runs properly.. see here: http://ideone.com/eISah

Comment: I'll bet you're on Windows. Try opening cmd.exe and invoking your program from the command line instead of double-clicking on it. That way that the window doesn't disappear when your program terminates.

Comment: lol I am on windows and yes it does work when I load it into an online compiler very strange that Outlook closes it so click even with a system ("pause")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to work, but personally I think I'd write it a bit differently:

```
std::string repeat(std::string const &input, size_t reps) { 
    std::ostringstream result;

    std::fill_n(
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(result), 
        reps, 
        input);

    return result.str();
}
```

Comment: thank you I appreciate it I am in Computer programming & science 181 sometimes you learn the hard way first

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Naveen above. No problems with this code when tried in online compiler. See http://codepad.org/PwDtkUEu
[image]
Any problem you are getting must be due to your compiler. Try rebulding your project.

Comment: @KcNorth: "Ty :) I appreciate the help" is best expressed ["by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).